# Does there exist a set of intervals, no 5 of which share a point, such that the interval graph is non-planar?

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

I'm having trouble proving this, but I assume I will need to make use of Euler's formula.

Comment: @saulspatz No subdivision on cycles can be chordal. That completes your proof. Want to write an answer?

Comment: @SK19 Thanks.  I don't really understand your comment.  Why don't you write an answer so I can learn something?  (Please elaborate on the comment.)

Comment: @saulspatz I was just reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski%27s_theorem and now I'm unsure. I thought the subdivision must be an induced subgraph and my argument only works then, because an induced subgraph of an interval graph is interval as well....

Comment: @SK19 I see what you mean, but I need to think about how to formalize it.  Thanks.

Comment: @SK19 My whole idea was wrong.  See Misha Lavrov's answer.

Answer (score 5):

Such sets do exist. Here's an example: take the interval graph generated by
$$
   \{[4,5], [6,7], [8,9], [1,10], [2,11], [3, 12]\}.
$$
The first three intervals are disjoint, and the last three intervals intersect all three of them, and each other. No point is contained in five or more intervals because it would need to be contained in two of the first three, which don't intersect.

The intersection graph they form is [the following](https://hog.grinvin.org/ViewGraphInfo.action?id=100):

[image]

It is not planar because it contains $K_{3,3}$ not just as a subdivision but as a subgraph: each of the first three vertices (drawn around the outside of the diagram above) is adjacent to each of the last three (drawn in the middle).